# Detect value out of range errors using type assertion in Golang

Tags: go, type-assertion, strconv

Given the following code:

```
iv, err := strconv.ParseInt("18446744073709551448", 10, 64)
fmt.Println(iv)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", err)
fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)

//Output:
9223372036854775807
&strconv.NumError{Func:"ParseInt", Num:"18446744073709551448", Err:(*errors.errorString)(0x1040a040)}
strconv.ParseInt: parsing "18446744073709551448": value out of range
```

How can I detect that the function failed due to being out of range of an int64? The [strconv.ParseInt](http://golang.org/src/strconv/atoi.go#L150) function returns an error type, but in this case it is actually a [strconv.NumError](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#NumError) type as indicated by `%#v`. The [Error Handling and Go](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) article mentions you can use type assertion to check for specific types of errors, but it doesn't give any examples. What expression should I use to complete this code:

```
if expression {
    uv, err := strconv.ParseUint("18446744073709551448", 10, 64)
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have,

> [Package strconv](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/)
>
> `var ErrRange = errors.New("value out of range")`
>
> [ErrRange](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#pkg-variables) indicates that a value is out of range for the target type.
>
> ```
> type NumError struct {
>         Func string // the failing function (ParseBool, ParseInt, ParseUint, ParseFloat)
>         Num  string // the input
>         Err  error  // the reason the conversion failed (ErrRange, ErrSyntax)
> }
> ```
>
> A [NumError](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#NumError) records a failed conversion.
>
> ```
> func (e *NumError) Error() string
> ```

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    iv, err := strconv.ParseInt("18446744073709551448", 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        if numError, ok := err.(*strconv.NumError); ok {
            if numError.Err == strconv.ErrRange {
                fmt.Println("Detected", numError.Num, "as a", strconv.ErrRange)
                return
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(iv)
}
```

Output:

```
Detected 18446744073709551448 as a value out of range
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted... Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if they added more examples. The error handling documentation didn't really cover this very well.

Answer (score -1):

The error that's returned from `strconv.ParseInt` is only known at compile time to be some type that implements the Error interface.  Type assertion allows you to insist that it's a `strconv.NumError` and inspect its fields directly, but at the risk of throwing a runtime panic if you turn out to be wrong:

```
if err.(*strconv.NumError).Err.Error() == "value out of range" {
    uv, err := strconv.ParseUint("18446744073709551448", 10, 64)
}
```

A more flexible solution (but maybe too loosey-goosey for your purposes) would be to perform a substring match on the `err.Error()` method:

```
if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "value out of range") {
    uv, err := strconv.ParseUint("18446744073709551448", 10, 64)
}
```

Comment: Looks like type assertions used in assignment or initialization have a second return of a boolean and do not cause a runtime panic https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

Comment: Good point. But to take advantage of the comma ok, you'll almost certainly need to make the type assertion all by itself and not also try to dereference `.Err.Error()`. i.e. `if ne, ok := err.(*strconv.NumError); ok { if ne.Err.Error() == "value out of range") { ... } }`

Comment: Mucking around with the string output of `Error()` in Go completely misses the point and is very bad practice.

Comment: I agree, I wasn't thinking through this problem clearly. I'm glad peterSO posted his superior solution.